# How to fix SVN Merge-Conflicts-Resolved and code changes Or SVN Revert

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution

May be this can seems simple for some one but I am having some serious issues with SVN Merge-Conflicts-Resolution-Code Change operations.

**Note: I am using TortoiseSVN GUI and I have merged from Merged Option**

Here are the steps what I followed:

> 1. I have Merged Br1 into Br2. (like Rev 123-Head (like 123-133) and Now Br1 has some new commits with Rev starting from 134...)
> 2. After Merging I received so many conflicts. (not committed yet)
> 3. I resolved conflicted files and also added some new codes to it. (not committed yet)
> 4. I commmitted some new changes in Br1. (still not committed Br2)

Now problem arised.

> Q1: I want to revert back my Merge from Br1 into Br2. Is it possible?

If Q1 is not possible then...

> Q2: Can I reverted back my new code changes in Br2 confilicted files?
>   So that those conflicted files again come into conflicted status (not
>   my resolved conflicts). So that again I can Merge fresh Br1 into Br2 with Br1's updated committed.

Aim is that, If I could able to revert back my newly added code to conflicted files then I can keep perfect Merge from Br1 into Br2 with all updated codes from Br1 into Br2.

Is it possible?

If I missed anything in above explanation then please let me know.

***Edit***

**Above Question in another way**

> 1. I have Merged Br1 into Br2.
> 2. So Br2 is in conflicted state (some files)
> 3. I have resolved conflicted files. (Still not committed)
> 4. I added some more code to those conflicted files (still not committed)
> 5. Now, I want to revert my changes (new added after resolving conflicted files)

Is it possible to get a state of conflicted files before I added some new code to it?

Comment: there should be an option to revert back the changes of Br2 to Head. Merging would be done on your local copy and you haven't committed yet. So I think you can just revert changes to head for Br2.

Comment: @Nikhil But can it create any problem? Because after My Merge in Br2 (1-Head). There are so many changes Made in Br1. So can it create any log info issue in SVN?

Comment: Were there any uncommitted changes in Br2 before merging changes of Br1 ?

Comment: @Nikhil Br2 was committed before Merging from Br1. Now after Merge from Br1 into Br2, Br2 is not committed yet. And about your question. No. There were no any uncommitted changes in Br2.

Comment: then you can just take backup of Br2(with current state)...and can revert it, after reverting, you can just try to merge Br1..there shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: @Nikhil, Will I receive my conflicted state of files which were before when I had Merged from Br1 into Br2? Or my Merge will also get lost?

Comment: When you revert it back, all of your code merger in Br2 would be lost.

Comment: @Nikhil, Again I will not merge it back, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39112/discussion-between-nikhil-and-nullpointer)